# Vertically align text that is surrounded by 2 buttons HTML/CSS so that the middle of text is the middle of buttons

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML to make buttons to change the size of an image:

```
<span class="size-change">
            <button id="minus">-</button>
            <p id="size-no">Size: 50</p>
            <button id="plus">+</button>
</span>
```

I styled it with the following CSS:

```
.size-change {
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

.size-change button {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
}
```

This is the result: [image]

However, what I'm trying to achieve is the case where the text in between is vertically aligned with the buttons at the centre. `text-align: center` also doesn't seem to work. Any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items ?

Comment: @Mue yup, just did that but thanks anyway!

Comment: instead of `p` you should use `output` or better yet even `input type number` for accessibility

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I immediately found the solution by applying `display: flex` on my container along with `align-items: center`